# Postgresql requests proxied by HTTP server

Tags: postgresql, proxy, apache2

I am using a mobile application that connects directly to the database instance (Postgres), as such, I have to keep the ports open for traffic that is generated from the internet (4G, mobile app).

This mobile app (QFIELD, mobile version of QGIS) has a direct connection to the database, this is the reason why the database is reachable from the internet on a public ip but this is a critical issue for the security of the data and the requests that can be sent to the database.

I would like to proxy the requests so that the database is only available to local machines and not open for connections directly.

The mobile appp would send the request to an HTTP url which would send the request to the local ip and port, this way I would avoid to have the database exposed on the internet.

Ideally, I would like to go from this app (which uses a postgres connection string to connect to the server) to an HTTP server that routes the request locally, as such:

- APP connects to https://myproxy/postgres
- Request is proxied to a local server

Can I do this with Apache2? Any ideas?

At the moment I cannot write a middleware that proxies requests from the APP to the local postgres.

Comment: "using an application that connects directly to the database" and "I have to keep the ports open for traffic that is generated from the internet (4G, mobile app)" don't really make sense together. Can you clarify WHERE your application lives? Is it a mobile phone app or something on the apache server you already have? You also appear to not want to change how your application operates AND change the protocol it is talking (from PostgreSQL's to HTTP). I don't see how that is supposed to be possible. Are you just looking for a PostgreSQL proxy like pgbouncer/pgpool?

Comment: @RichardHuxton i changed the description a bit, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is expecting to connect directly to a PostgreSQL database and you don't want to change that then you need to connect to something that "speaks" PostgreSQL's client protocol.

You can place a proxy such as pgbouncer or pgpool in front of it, but they aren't a guarantee of greater security just by themselves. This is the same problem as with any proxy - it is just forwarding requests and responses to your actual server so any vulnerability is still exposed.

What you can do is:

- restrict the number of connections at the proxy point
- restrict which users can connect non-locally to your PostgreSQL cluster
- restrict where they can connect from to just your proxy
- restrict those users permissions within the database(s)

That last point is particularly important - assume any user account your application can be used maliciously. Restrict the account to prevent mass updating or deleting of data. Also take special care to restrict access to other users' data.

If I was forced to allow access like this, I would want one PostgreSQL user account per actual user at the very least. In practice I wouldn't get to this point with a production application.